# Playa fields: can I pair one channel entry to another and populate similar channel fields in template?

Tags: playa, ifelse

I'm an EE novice working on a big site. I have a configuration concept in my head and I want to know if it's doable. Please bear with my limited knowledge of EE lingo. I'm still learning.

So I have a channel **Speaker** whose channel fields include Name, Topic, Bio, etc. I have another channel **Multimedia** which includes many of the same kinds of channel fields: Title, Subtitle, Description, etc.

We have speakers come in regularly and give a presentation. We create their Speaker entry long before their event. After the event we produce a video and create the Multimedia entry for that event. We do multimedia for other types of events which is why we don't just have a multimedia channel field in the Speaker channel.

Is there a way for me to add a Playa channel field to Multimedia, connecting a Multimedia entry to a Speaker entry, and then populate the template with Speaker info?

Something like this (this is again, theoretical, but if you feel the need to correct my syntax, go right ahead):

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="Multimedia"}
  {if playa_field}
    {playa_field}
      <h1>{speaker_name}</h1>
      <h2>{speaker_topic}</h2>
      <p>{speaker_bio}</p>
    {/playa_field}
  {if:else}
    <h1>{media_title}</h1>
    <h2>{media_subtitle}</h2>
    <p>{media_desc}</p>
  {/if}
  <video src="{media_url}">Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video.</video>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

(edit: removed a redundant `{/if}` thanks to syntax correction in comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it exactly right, save one syntax error - after `{/playa_field}`, you should go right to `{if:else}`, skipping the `{/if}`.

Comment: I can't believe I got it exactly right. I just tried it and it works! Okay so next step... can I store all those Speaker channel field values for use elsewhere in the template?

Like maybe...

`{playa_field
      speaker_name="{speaker_name}"
      speaker_topic="{speaker_topic}"
      speaker_bio="{speaker_bio}"
}
{/playa_field}`

Comment: Hmm, not sure what you want to do there. Fieldtype tags are for getting data, not setting data. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Nevermind. It's not a big hassle to make more than one IF statement.